# Symfony 2 File Constraint

Tags: symfony

I have a standard class that handles creating a file upload form and I want to add some validation for the fields, like maxSize for example.

Here is my $collectionConstraint. This does not work.

```
$collectionConstraint = new Collection(
    array(
        'fields' => array(
            'file_1'            => array(new FileValidator(array('maxSize' => '4M'))),
            'file_2'            => array()
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your $collectionConstraints should look like:

```
$collectionConstraints = new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Collection(array(
    'fields' => array(
        'file1' => new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\File(array('maxSize' => '4M'),
    ),
);
```

[See here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/constraints/Collection.html) for more information about using a Constraints Collection.